# How to change fetch call and rerender screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, react-native, fetch

I have a React Native App that is communicating with a PostgresDB threw a ExpressJS REST API.

I have a fetchcall that gives back some data that I want to display inside my app. It calls the route with two params. One being the userid that I stored inside AsyncStorage and the other one being the selected Date that is stored in my state.

My problem is that the fetch url should be updated when the date state changes and then give back the data for the given day. Currently it is not rerendering the screen but the date changes. Is there a specific way how to tell my fetch query that it should rerender?

For example: `` `http://myip/api/hours/daydata/${realDate}/${userid}` ``
is my fetchurl and realDate is this.state.date and userid is the AsyncStorage stored userid.

`` `http://myip/api/hours/daydata/2019-11-06/138` `` this url gives me back the data I need for the given day and for the user.

On a Button click my date state changes for example to 2019-11-07.
`` `http://myip/api/hours/daydata/2019-11-07/138` `` this would be the new url that should be fetched next and I expect to rerender the screen to see the changes. But it doesnt rerender!

Here you have some code:

```
 async fetchData() {
    let realDate = this.state.date;
    await getData("userid")      // asyncStorage gets userid correctly
      .then(data => data)
      .then(value => this.setState({ userid: value }))
      .catch(err => console.log("AsyncS_Error: " + err));

    const userid = this.state.userid;
    console.log("cpmDM id_ " + userid);


    await fetch(
      `http://myip/api/hours/daydata/${realDate}/${userid}`
      )
      .then(console.log("realD8_: " + realDate))
      .then(res => res.json())
      // .then(res => console.log(res))
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res[0].remark);
        return this.setState({ 
          remark: res[0].remark
        });
      }) 
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }


componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
```

I expect to get a rerender because I am calling setState on remark.
In the first render the remark from the first selected date gets diplayed but as I change the day the remark stays and doesnt update.

Ideas:

Is there a way to log the current fetchurl? Do I need something like componentWillUpdate maybe?

EDIT: This is the way that my state gets updated:

```
dateForwardHandler = () => {
    console.log("Current Date:", this.state.date);

    const newDate = Moment(this.state.date).add(1, "d").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    this.setState({ date: newDate.toString() });

    console.log("Current Date:", this.state.date);
  };
```

EDIT 2.0:

calling fetchData() inside the dateBackHandler and dateForwardHandler is actually showing me the different remarks where I need them but somehow they are 1 day off. If I go back in date for ex to the 25.10 I get the remark from the 26.10 and when I then go to 24.10 I get the one from 25.10

Seems like the component does not get updated on the first press but on the second so its one day off.

EDITS MERGED: Soo thanks for all the help that you guys gave me.

I want to tell you how the app is behaving currently.

```
dateForwardHandler = () => {
    console.log("Current Date:", this.state.date);

    const newDate = Moment(this.state.date).add(1, "d").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    this.setState({ date: newDate.toString() });

    console.log("Current Date:", this.state.date);

    this.fetchData();   // THIS CALL IS NEW 
  };
```

By calling this.fetchData(); after the state changes and on Button Press I get some different remarks shown but a Problem I have is that it is always one day off. So somehow the frontend and the fetchcall are not updating at the same time.
But I think it is right to first set the state.date to the new date and then to call fetchData...

Thanks for all the help so far ;)

Comment: Do you call `fetchData` after you change the `date` property in the state ? Something like `this.setState({ date: newDate }, fetchData)` ?

Comment: When you change the day, are you updating the state of `realDate` with the newly selected date?

Comment: Please check my EDIT ty for your responses.

Comment: Can you call this.fetchData(); right after setting new date value , ie after this.setState({ date: newDate.toString() });

Comment: Why do you need to update your state with the current date? Can't you get current date just before the fetch? Having  `let realDate =  Moment().add(1, "d").format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString();`, this way the date will always be latest

Comment: @Ajith thanks for your tip I am actually seeing some changes now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to return `this.setState`, so instead of

```
return this.setState({ 
 remark: res[0].remark
});
```

use

```
this.setState({ 
 remark: res[0].remark
});
```

Comment: Temporary fix will be to use this.forceUpdate()

Comment: Possible yes but you should not use this.forceUpdate() because it is not reacts flow to force a rerender like this.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the current date in your state and update it everytime when needed? cannot you just do:

```
let currentDate = Moment().add(1, "d").format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString()
```

This way you don't force a re-render everytime you update the date, while still fetching with the date in the moment you are fetching

Comment: When I run the date should be todays date and if i click forward or back button the date should change displaying the remark from the selected date that is stored in the db. I am not really getting what your approach does u mean I should call this before the fetch? because this method adds a day to the current date

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would not put two awaits into one single async function. It could be the your userId will not be retrieved in time for your fetch method.

Regarding the rerendering, try to first return the result of fetchData (res.json) and then setState outside of the async function.

EDIT:

As you mentioned that you wanted to do on button click, it could look somewhat like this:

```
fetchData = (url, method) => {
    let error;
    return fetch(url, {
      method: method,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json().then(response => ({ response })).catch((error) => { console.log("JSON cannot be parsed") });
      } 
      error = JSON.stringify(response);
      return ({ error });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Promise rejected");
    });
  }



onButtonPress = async () => {    
    const userid = this.state.userid;
    const realDate = this.state.realDate;
    const { response, error } = await this.fetchData('http://myip/api/hours/daydata/${realDate}/${userid}', 'GET'); 
    if (response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({ 
          remark: response[0].remark
        });
    } else {
        console.error("Error: " + error);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show me your approach with my code? also my userid gets stored on the login page and it is in the first await so shouldnt it always be there ?

Comment: @yesIamFaded I appended an example to my answer

Comment: Thank you I will look into it.